# opencv2.framework not compile with linker flag -ObjC

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, opencv, linker-flags

I'm using the latest version of *opencv* ([opencv 2.4.9](http://opencv.org/downloads.html)) and I have to have the **-ObjC flag**, required by *Core Plot* (a plotting framework).

When I set **-ObjC** in the other flags, I get a lot of errors (28 actually) of type : `Undefined symbols for architecture i386` as follow :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer", referenced from:
-[CaptureDelegate captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
CvCaptureFile::retrieveFramePixelBuffer() in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
-[CvVideoCamera captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in opencv2(cap_ios_video_camera.o)
"_CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp", referenced from:
-[CvVideoCamera captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in opencv2(cap_ios_video_camera.o)
"_CMSampleBufferInvalidate", referenced from:
CvCaptureFile::retrieveFramePixelBuffer() in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
"_CMTimeMake", referenced from:
CvCaptureCAM::startCaptureDevice(int) in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
CvVideoWriter_AVFoundation::writeFrame(_IplImage const*) in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
-[CvVideoCamera createVideoDataOutput] in opencv2(cap_ios_video_camera.o)
"_CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetPresentationDimensions", referenced from:
CvCaptureCAM::getProperty(int) in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
"_CVBufferRelease", referenced from:
-[CaptureDelegate captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
-[CaptureDelegate updateImage] in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
CvCaptureFile::retrieveFramePixelBuffer() in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
... etc
```

It is the same problem as [Bartosz Bialecki](http://answers.opencv.org/question/20152/ios-opencv2framework-not-compile-with-linker-flag/), I tried the proposed solution but problem's still here.

Does anyone have an idea ?

### EDIT :

**Here are all the framework I included :**

[image]

Comment: Most of those symbols are from CoreMedia, so adding the CoreMedia framework to your project will help a lot.  It looks like there's also a lot of opencv symbols undefined as well.

Comment: It is already added... Please see my edit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Problem solved adding several frameworks :
`CoreVideo.framework`, `AssetsLibrary.framework`, `CoreMedia.framework`.

**Here is the complete list of the included frameworks :**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Below is the list frameworks you need to import into your project to build success. and here is the [relate link](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/ios/video_processing/video_processing.html)

```
AVFoundation
opencv2

Accelerate

AssetsLibrary

CoreGraphics

CoreImage

CoreMedia

CoreVideo

QuartzCore

UIKit
```

Answer (score -1):

Adding below frameworks worked for me

- AVFoundation
- CoreMedia
- AssetLibrary
- CoreVideo